# Average complicated

Tags: powerbi, report, business-intelligence, powerbi-desktop

I have 2 tables CARS_MODEL and INCIDENT with the relation 1..*
A car model has a name and belong to a group so a group could own n car model.

An incident has OPEN DATE and CLOSE DATE. I added in the tab INCIDENT a column to calculate the gap between these 2 dates (named Treating Time).Then, I created a measure calculating the average of TREATING TIME (named Treating Time Average) that I used as value in my bar chart and with attribute GROUP as Axe. So I have the average of time that each group needs to treat an incident. So each group has a different average.

Now, I would like to calculate the gap between this Average and the average of time that 1 group needs to treat an incident(a measure that I created named Average Group). In fact. I programed a measure to substract Treating Time Average to the Average Group in order of getting the gap. Nevertheless, I don't know why I didn't obtain the correct Average group which is much lower than all the average of each group.

You have the PIBX here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VgmYUSGPIoSmpWlmsUIpIIIx5GwKLoRf

Comment: Although I'm not completely sure about your goal, the calculation of Average Group looks to be erroneous. Current implementation of Average Group always returns 4.81, which is the overall Average (14.44) divided by the number of Groups with incidents (3), regardless of which Group is sliced.

Comment: Hello
I know that my calculation of Average Grroup is wrong but I don't know know how to fix it. Is that the conception of data is wrong or there is something missing ?
Could you help me to find out a solution ?

Comment: Can you give a clearer description of "the average of time that 1 group needs to treat an incident"? How is that different from the overall average of 14.44?

Comment: Yes of course :
The overall average : Among only incidents which are treated, each of them needs a certain amount of time to be treated. I would like to know how much is the average .
The average of time that 1 group needs to treat an incident : Each group has taken a certain amount of time to treat ONE incident so each group has a different average of treating time.

Comment: So the average group is SUM of treating time of each group / N groups.
The condition is : a group has minimum 1 incident

Comment: Still struggling to understand. Is that same or different from "avg" measure in the PBIX when it is sliced by Group, for example 13.0 = (24 + 10 + 6 + 15 + 10) / 5 for Group 1? It is helpful if you could show some examples of how to calculate with real numbers.

Comment: Sorry if it's still strunggling to understand

You're right for the Group 1.
It's the same calcul for Group 2  = 13 and Group 3  = (17 +18 + 17) / 3=17,3. Group 4 is not taken into account because it doesn't have any incidents

Then, to get the "avg group": (13 + 13 + 17,3) / 3 = 14,3

Final step: Create a measure to substract the Average of each group to the Average Group :  "avg" - "avg group"
Group 1 : 13 - 14,3 = -1,3
Group 2 : 13 - 14,3 = -1,3
Group 3 : 17,3 - 14,3 = 3

Comment: I tried this following solution : 

I created a table "Group" to calculate the average of each group then I change the "avg group" like following : CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Group'[Treating time]);ALL(Car))

You can find out the new PIBX here : 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AvpWdSFXBb1HztRBwbqa5KFNcUDZUSwh. Could you tell me if it's correct ?

Comment: Thank you for sharing that. The new version is returning a different result from what you described above, but it looks more making sense. Anyway, it turned clear enough for me to post an answer, thanks!

Comment: I forgot an important detail : I will have to be able to filter data by car model. And I just tried to deselect some car model and the "avg group" doesn't change and it's not correct. I'm finally so disapointed cause of this problem !!!

Comment: What is the expected result in that case? If I select A8022 for example, should "avg group" be (24 + 10) / 2 = 17 for Group 1, and there are no results for the other Groups?

Comment: if we don't use filter , the average of the group 1 : (24 + 10 + 6 + 15 + 10) / 5. Then if we use filter to deselect F3359 (1 of 2 car model of group 1) so the average become indeed : (24+10) / 2 = 17 . It will change also the "average group". Consequently, when a filter is used, all the data concerned should be removed from all calculations

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, the gap has been defined as simple as `AVERAGE ( Incident[Treating Time] ) - [Average Group]` and there is no discussion here. The point is how to calculate Average Group.

There would be several possible answers depending on how you define Average Group, which is "the average of time that 1 group needs to treat an incident".

### Answer 1: Overall average regardless of the Group filter

Average Group is defined as the average treating time of all incidents regardless of which group it is related to. In other words, it is calculated as the average of Incident[Treating Time] ignoring the filters which may have been applied on Car[Group] column. It calculates the average of all Incidents related to any Group, even if the report is filtered for a specific Group.

In this case, the measure would be defined as below. It is calculating the AVERAGE of Incident[Treating Time] removing any filter having been applied on Car[Group].

```
Average Group =
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGE ( Incident[Treating Time] ),
    REMOVEFILTERS ( Car[Group] )
)
```

### Answer 2: Average of group averages

Average Group is defined as the average of average treating times of each group. The calculation should follow two steps: 1. Evaluate AVERAGE of Incident[Treating Time] for each Group separately, then 2. Calculate the AVERAGE of the results of step 1. Also in this scenario, the filters having been applied on Car[Group] column should be removed.

```
Average Group2 =
VAR GroupAverages = ADDCOLUMNS (
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( Car[Group] ),
        REMOVEFILTERS ( Car[Group] )
    ),
    "@Avg", CALCULATE ( AVERAGE ( Incident[Treating Time] ) )
)
RETURN AVERAGEX ( GroupAverages, [@Avg] )
```

> Note, average of averages is not a meaningful calculation in general, because it does not consider the number of occurrences in each group. However I posted this because OP is looking for a way to achieve this, and there would probably be some value to add a reusable DAX pattern here in SO.

Comment: There could be some data in the tab INCIDENT which doesn't match with data of the tab CAR and vice versa. So I added another condition in your 2 measures just after the function REMOVEFILTERS : FILTER(Incident;Incident[Car Model]=RELATED(Car[Car Model])). So it eliminate the occurence OP192 with the Treating Time = 30 because this model doesn't belong to the tab CAR. What do you think ?

Comment: I calculate the average of the average because I would like to know relative to the AVERAGE GROUP, how much is the gap for each group. Is their treating time  above the AVERAGE GROUP or below. It allows to make a competition between groups. Do you think it is more meaningful ?

Comment: I know how you are dealing with the missing Car, but did not mentioned about it in the answer because it is not essential and too much detail for anyone else visiting this page. Your formula works perfectly. But I would do `FILTER ( Indicent, NOT ISBLANK ( RELATED ( Car[Car Model] ) ) )` because this sounds more straightforward.

Comment: It is totally depending on your business whether "average of averages" makes sense or not. I personally believe it is nonsense. Suppose if there are only two groups, one group has 100 incidents while the other has only 5, and there is a big difference in treating time, say 20 vs 8. The group average will be (20 + 8) / 2 =14, but this is far different from the true average 19.42. However, if you or your client decided "average of averages" is more preferable, then that is the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry but I applicated your solution but in the chart "GAP BY GROUP" , I have nothing because for each group, the "Average Group2" = the average of the group so the result is always = 0

Comment: Are you using Car[Group] or Group[Group] for axis? Above should work only for Car[Group].

Comment: Sounds like REMOVEFILTERS is not working and there should be some error around there. If you can provide more context or share the file I might be able to find the bug. But before doing that, I hope you do the best to understand the code and find the way yourself.

Comment: yes I will try to understand the code first and come back if necessary , thank you very much !!!